# Numbers in body and footing do not match

Tags: footnotes

I’m using `\footnote` or `\footnotemark` depending on how convenient the location of the reference is. For some reason, I correctly get the numbers 1 and 2 in the body, but in the footing I have two footnotes with the number 2. My editor/compiler is Kile.

I cannot see what might be wrong. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

This footnote\footnotemark  is in the middle of a sentence. However, this one
is at the end of it.\footnote{Text of the second footnote}

\footnotetext{Text of the first footnote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your problem is the use of `\footnote` in between. `\footnotetext` does not increase the counter, because then `\footnotemark` would be senseless. You would have to switch the usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could force the `\footnotetext` to use value 1 by

```
\footnotetext[1]{....]
```

But at the position that you use it it would still come after the second footnote so they would be associated the correct number but come in the wrong order.

if it is "safe" to use `\footnote` at the end of the paragraph for your second footnote, you can put the `\footnotetext` at the same position.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

This footnote\footnotemark  is in the middle of a sentence. However, this one
is at the end of it.\footnotetext{Text of the first footnote}\footnote{Text of the second footnote}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I’m not interested in forcing the numbers because it would be very hard to keep track of it. However, your suggestion of using `\footnotetext` at the same position of `\footnote` fixed the problem.